# export default connect( mapStateToProps )( withRouter( app) ) not passing mapStateToProps to next component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-2016

I want to pass `mapStateToProps` value to next component while using `withRouter` so that i can maintain `this.props.history` also.
Here is my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class MyApp extends React.Component {
    constructor ( props ) {
        super( props );
        this.state = {}
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        // it is printing empty array i.e. []
        console.log( " this.props.userDetails ", this.props.userDetails )
    }
    routeChange = () => {
        let path = `/someurl`;
        this.props.history.push( path );
    };

    render() {
        return <div>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary"
                data-target="#add"
                id="addnew"
                onClick={ this.routeChange }
            >
        </div>
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        userDetails: state.UserDetailsReducer.userDetails
    };
};
export default withRouter( connect( mapStateToProps )( MyApp ) );
```

I tried both

```
export default connect( mapStateToProps )( withRouter( MyApp ) );
```

and

`export default withRouter( connect( mapStateToProps )( MyApp  ) );`

and

```
export default compose(  withRouter,  connect( mapStateToProps ))( App );
```

but the value is empty array.
Here is another file.

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import UserDetails from '../store/Actions/UserDetails'; 

const NavigationBar = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`###REACT_APP_PLATFORM_URL###/access/userinfo`, requestOptions)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status != 200) { setisError(true) }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((findresponse) => {
                if (findresponse.msg) { setstatus(findresponse.msg) }
                else {
                    setcheckName(findresponse);
                    props.getUserDetails(findresponse) 
                }
            })
            .catch(error => { });
    }, []); 
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        userDetails: state.UserDetailsReducer.userDetails
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getUserDetails: (user) => dispatch(UserDetails(user))
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NavigationBar);
```

Comment: The fact that it's an empty array and not undefined tells me it's working. What does your state look like?

Comment: its not empty array, it has values it was initialized by const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getUserDetails: (user) => dispatch(UserDetails(user))
    }
} in another component.

Comment: Are you mutating the array in redux by any chance which is causing it not to result in a re-render of this component when it's updated? Post your reducer code.

Comment: @Adam `import { USERDETAILS } from '../Types/ActionTypes';

const InitialState = {
    userDetails: []
}

const UserDetailsReducer = (state = InitialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case USERDETAILS:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                userDetails: action.payload
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default UserDetailsReducer;`

Comment: @Adam `export default function rootReducer(asyncReducers) {
  return combineReducers({
    ToolsDetails,
    CartridgeDetails,
    UserReducer,
    PipelineDetails,
    UserDetailsReducer,
    ProjectDetailsReducer,
    ...asyncReducers
  })
}`

Comment: You should add these as edits to your answer instead of posting them in comments. But that reducer function looks fine.